# Determining whether a given algebraic number is an algebraic integer

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

Let $K$ be a number field and let $\mathcal{O}_{K}$ be the ring of integers of $K$, then given a random element $\alpha$ from our number field $K$, is there any quick and efficient way to determine whether that said element belongs to $\mathcal{O}_{K}$?

The only one I know is to calculate the minimal polynomial of that element and then from that see whether it belongs to $\mathcal{O}_{K}$ or not, but it feels quite a long and inefficient process, is there any quicker way to do it?

Comment: How are you given the element?

Comment: Well, generally the field $K = \mathbb{Q}(\theta)$, and  the element is some combination of that $\theta$, so for e.g. something like $\frac{1+\theta^{2}}{3}$, or some other combination

Comment: And how is $\theta$ given?

Comment: It can be given as anything, say $\sqrt{17}$ for e.g.

Comment: I'm pretty sure there is no "quick and efficient" way to do this in general.  in some specific number fields there will be ways, but not in the generality in which you asked.

Comment: Oh Ok, so the only way would be to work out the minimal polynomial and then just checking it?

Comment: If it's given as $\sqrt{17}$, then it's pretty easy to tell whether $(1+\theta^2)/3$ is an algebraic integer. The questions I am asking you are not trivial, and they're not asked just to be annoying.

Comment: Oh, i wasn't annoyed at all, but looking at Gregory's comments, I can see why your questions make sense, i suppose it really does depend on the number field given

Comment: Maybe this is a question that first needs to be narrowed down and then broadened back out. Like maybe, a random element of an imaginary quadratic field.

Answer (score 0):

$\mathcal{O}_{K}$ is a very good ring (it is noetherian, integrally closed and all prime ideal is maximal). However, despite of this rather strong structure, it is in general, for practical calculations, very difficult or impossible what you ask. I wonder of one possibility: a being an integer of $\mathcal{O}_{K}$  we must have by an equivalent definition of the integer a that $\mathbb{Z}$[a] is a $\mathbb{Z}$-module of finite type. Therefore you can try to prove that M = $\mathbb{Z}$ +a$\mathbb{Z}$ + $a^2$$\mathbb{Z}$ +....+$a^{n-1}$$\mathbb{Z}$ contains all the powers $a^m$ of your integer a what is deduced (theorethically not practically!) from the monic polynomial you want not to use (practically!).It is maybe a way to answer (not completely!) your question, but I repeat, in general it is impossible (just for quadratic fields you can do it easily). Sorry for bad English.

**Additional note**.- n is the degree of K; if $a^{n+1}$ is not in M, you win. It seems the method works.

Answer (score 0):

The method is based on the following theorem

> Let $G$ be an additive subgroup of $\mathcal O$ of rank equal to the degree of $K$, with $\mathbb Z$-basis $\{\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\dotsc,\alpha_n\}$. Then $|\mathcal O/G|^2$ divides $\Delta[\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\dotsc,\alpha_n]$.

And we have the proposition

> suppose that $G\neq\mathcal O$. Then there exists an integer of the form
>   $$
> \frac1p(\lambda_1\alpha_1+\dotsb+\lambda_n\alpha_n)\tag{I}\label{I}
> $$
>   where $0\le\lambda_i<p$ are rational integers and $p$ is a prime such that $p^2$ divides $\Delta_G$.

The idea is

> Start with an initial guess $G$ for $\mathcal O$.
>   Compute $\Delta_G$.
>   For each prime $p$ whose square devides $\Delta_G$, test all numbers of the form $\eqref{I}$ to see which are algebraic integers.
>   If any new integers arise, enlarge $G$ to a new $G'$ by adding a new number.
>   Repeat until no new algebraic integers are found.

Comment: The question was not to find a basis for $\mathcal{O}_K$, but to check whether a particular element is integral.

Comment: Ohhhhhhhhh.....you're right....